# configuring mongoDB with Django

Tags: django, mongodb, python-2.7, django-models

For few days I have been searching for a tutorial that shows how MongoDB can be used as a database with Django but resulted in nothing fruitful or clear tutorial. There have been questions regarding this in this forum most of them directed to look up for http://www.django-mongodb.org/ but I find there's something else written. Can anybody suggest me some good tutorial or pointers where I can start with.
P.S. I myself have searched a lot but couldn't find anything that tells the whole procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main options tu use MongoDB with Django are:

- [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/) is an ORM for MongoDB with some [Django Integration](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html). This will not replace the Django ORM, but you're free not to use it.
- [Django MongoDB Engine](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/) provides a tighter intgration in Django by providing a MongoDB backend to the Django ORM, but requires the use of [Django-nonrel](http://django-nonrel.org/), a fork of Django that adds support for non-relational databases.

The Django MongoDB Engine documentation formerly known as http://www.django-mongodb.org/  is now available at https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/. For future reference, you can get the previous version of the site using the Internet Archive's [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20121222013356/http://django-mongodb.org/).

Comment: what is MongoDB engine? How is it different from simple MongoDB or is it same?

Comment: Django MongoDB Engine allows the Django ORM to use MongoDB as a storage backend. But as explained in my **updated** answer, this requires the use of a forked Django version.

Comment: hi I voted for your answer as this provided me some pointers but i am still skeptic whether there are other integration forms available so once i knw it i can mark it as correct answer